# Not echoing checked checkboxes

Tags: php, html

```
 echo "<form action='recent.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
        echo "<table id='logs' border='1' cellspacing='0' width='62%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Time Logged</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Username</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>Password</th>";
        echo "<th width='15%'>IP Address</th>";
        echo "<th width='2%'><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"checkAll(this);\">Mark</a></th>";
        echo "<th width='2%'>Delete</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo ("<p><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td><i>$row[3]</i></td><td><center><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mark[]\" value=\"$row[0]\" id=\"$row[0]\"></center></td><td><a href=\"delete.php?time=$row[2]&user=$row[0]&pass=$row[1]&ip=$row[3]\"><center>[x]</center></a></td></p>");
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
```

The checkbox `<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"mark[]\" value=\"$row[0]\" id=\"$row[0]\">`
Then I have

```
if ($_GET['mark']) {
            foreach ($_GET['mark'] as $mark) {
                echo "<li>$mark</li>";
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't show any checked checkboxes.  And I also tried putting `<input type="submit">` before the closing `</form>` and it still didn't echo results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form is POSTed but you're looking in $_GET.

Comment: what do you mean checked attribute?

Comment: He means your form method = POST, and you are looking the in the $_GET superglobal.  You need to look in $_POST.

Comment: Ignore my previous answer, I've edited it now, I thought you were trying to show the input as checked from the start.  Then I understood your question and found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your HTML is just bad markup.

This is wrong `<p><td></td></p>`
It should be `<td><p></p></td>`
And `<center></center>` tags are deprecated.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="value" name="name" checked />
```

Comment: why downvoted?  he is right.  May not solve the problem but does not mean he does not have a point.

Comment: @rayman86: If it doesn't solve the problem, it shouldn't be posted as an **Answer**. That's what *comments* are for.

Comment: if I had the reputation to comment I would.

Comment: actually I just earned enough reputation to comment outside of my own answers

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless there's some new php syntax I haven't heard of (which is quite possible), don't you have to jump out of the string to use PHP variables?  Like this:

```
echo "<li>".$mark."</li>";
```

If that's true, you have the same problem in your top script.

Comment: No, not with double-quoted strings or the heredoc syntax.

Comment: PHP code echoed with double quotes does not need to be jumped out of to echo variables.  PHP will automatically plug the variable values in a double quote string where it sees them.  Single quote ones will have to be jumped out to get the value, however. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Not necessary when using double-quotes.